# Angular 6 and service workers

Tags: angular, service-worker

I am new to subject of service workers in angular and I need some info.

Mainly I have a app in angular and it makes request to some server by rest, but now I want to make sort of background worker, a mechanism that will once per 30 minutes, send a request to server or some info example status and cache it, and of course refresh it after that 30 minutes time period.

Will service workers will be able to do that? And if not what should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course service workers will be able to do that.

The main advantage of using them is that your periodic "heartbeat" will not block the UI when being triggered, and thus it won't affect UX at all.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service that will handle that.
In that service use `Observable.timer(time1, time2)` that emits first value after `time1` milliseconds and then every `time2` milliseconds. When it ticks, get the data from server and then update the data in a component that subscribes to this service.